# Copying a bitarray in a larger one (right justified)

Tags: c#, vb.net, clone, bitarray

I have to create a new `bitarray` larger of an existing one (one element more at the beginning) and copy it at the end of the *new* `bitarray`.

I have done this so far, but looks pretty ugly:

```
BitArray New_Ft = new BitArray(Ft.Length + 1);
for (int i = 0; i <= Ft.Length - 1; i++) {
    New_Ft(i + 1) = Ft(i);
}
```

Is there a smarter way (some global copy or so) ?

Comment: I think your way is actually pretty good. Not sure there's an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to create a temporary array.
Not necessary `Byte[]` could be `int[]` or `Bool[]`.

```
        Byte[] bits = new Byte[Ft.Length + 1];
        Ft.CopyTo(bits, 0);
        BitArray New_Ft = new BitArray(bits);
```

Comment: Thanks. It's pretty funny that Ft.CopyTo(bits, 1); will not take the new bitarray as argument. I don't understand why is that !?

Comment: @Pam: It's because `BitArray` does not inherit from `System.Array`.

Comment: Yes sure. Formally. But why a bitarray parameter is not considered in the CopyTo() It's natural that often one wants to copy a bitarray into another bitarray. And not to an array.

Comment: If there are no other smart suggestions or ideas, I think I will accept this one. (Even though i am not convinced this is actually better than the loop, at this point.)

Comment: One last crazy shot: do you think it would be possible to formally "fool" (with some type converter) the CopyTo() so that the argument looks like to it as an array ?